# intellij idea видит только public и default схемы postgres

Tags: postgresql, intellij-idea

при подключении postgres бд в идее в табе со схемами отображаются все схемы данной бд, но далее, когда уже все подключил и выбрал(например все) схемы, то отображаются только public и default, при том, что в другой схеме(созданной мною) и таблицы есть